# TexStudio Table Notes error

Tags: threeparttable

I am getting an error in the tablenotes.

This is my table:

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'BEKK'
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{BEKK estimates: Full Period}
\begin{center}
    \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\toprule
Variables & Coefficient & T-Statistic \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{1}$} & 0.0086** & 10.4233 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{2}$} & 0.0014 & 0.7898 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{3}$} & -0.0012 & -0.3242 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{4}$} & 0.0124** & 4.6625 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{5}$} & 0.0149 **& 2.8992 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{6}$} & 0.0284** & 5.7328 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\beta_{1}$} & 0.9393** & 88.6428 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\beta_{2}$} & 0.9081** & 46.9686 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\beta_{3}$} & 0.8211** & 14.8787 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\alpha_{1}$} & 0.2444** & 7.6211 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\alpha_{2}$} & 0.4089** & 9.9248 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\alpha_{3}$} & 0.3615** & 7.1682 \\
      \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tablenotes}
Notes: Double asterisks (**) represent significance at the 1\% level.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
\label{tab:bekk1}%
\end{table}%
```

I have all the following packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{longtable}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know `threeparttable`   well, but it appears that `tablenotes` is a list type environment, and you therefore need one or more `\item`s in it. Hence, use

```
\begin{tablenotes}
\item Notes: Double asterisks (**) represent significance at the 1\% level.
\end{tablenotes}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{BEKK estimates: Full Period}
\begin{center}
    \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\toprule
Variables & Coefficient & T-Statistic \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{1}$} & 0.0086** & 10.4233 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{2}$} & 0.0014 & 0.7898 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{3}$} & -0.0012 & -0.3242 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{4}$} & 0.0124** & 4.6625 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{5}$} & 0.0149 **& 2.8992 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\omega_{6}$} & 0.0284** & 5.7328 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\beta_{1}$} & 0.9393** & 88.6428 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\beta_{2}$} & 0.9081** & 46.9686 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\beta_{3}$} & 0.8211** & 14.8787 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\alpha_{1}$} & 0.2444** & 7.6211 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\alpha_{2}$} & 0.4089** & 9.9248 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\alpha_{3}$} & 0.3615** & 7.1682 \\
      \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tablenotes}
\item Notes: Double asterisks (**) represent significance at the 1\% level.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
\label{tab:bekk1}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: What might be the problem that I still get the message "unrecognised command" when putting the cursor over \begin\end{tablenotes}? I included an \item command and the threeparttable package as well.

Comment: @Lucas In what context? Is it TeXstudio telling you this? Just because TeXstudio is unaware of the existence of the `tablenotes` environment doesn't mean that it doesn't work. If you compile the document does the process finish without errors, and do you get a PDF? If so, nothing is wrong of course.

Comment: Yes it does compile and I do get a pdf as I want, but I just learned to be suspicious about error messages, warnings and other stuff because correcting afterwards can be quite tough. So, also I do not get any message in the Log I would like the red marking of the syntax `\begin{tablenotes}` `\end{tablenotes}` to disappear. TeXStudio tells me when I move the cursor above this marking that the command is not recognized. How can I make TeXStudio recognize it?

Comment: @Lucas Please ask a new question about that, if you cannot find another post where it has been answered already, I don't know and comments aren't really the place for it. (No one will see it.)